# How to remove all SVN settings from an Xcode4 project?

Tags: svn, xcode4

I have an Xcode4 project using SVN, and now want to switch to Git. But I can't find any settings UI for this. Is it fine with just deleting `.svn` directory? Or should I do this with preferred way?

Comment: @Alex No I'm using Xcode4's SVN feature and sometimes, command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that turns a plain regular folder into a Subversion working copy is the `.svn` folders. If you have a working copy and want to make it unrelated to SVN (i.e. make it a regular folder), all you need to do is delete the `.svn` folders throughout the directory tree.

The simplest way to do that is to perform `svn export` from the working copy to itself (at least with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html#tsvn-dug-export-unversion), not sure about other clients).